# Deploy CloudFunctions in VPC SC with cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

On GCP project, protected using VPC Service Control,I tried to deploy cloud functions with Cloud Build, but got error when deploy with gcloud command.

## Procedure

### 1 add cloudbuild service account in VPC SC

written in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#grant-build-access), I need to add `my-project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` in limit access

```
$ gcloud access-context-manager levels describe MY-ACCESS-LEVEL-POLICY

     basic:
      conditions:
      - ipSubnetworks:
        - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ( my local machine IP)
        members:
        - serviceAccount:my-project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
        - serviceAccount:service-my-project-number@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

[other article](https://cloud-ace.jp/tech_blog/vpcsc-with-functions/) says I also need to add  `service-my-project-number@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` so I did it.

### 2 set VPC SC restricted service

I already have service perimeters, whose restrictedServices contains

```
 - cloudbuild.googleapis.com,
 - cloudfunctions.googleapis.com,
```

### 3 deploy with gcloud command

this function need to connect CloudSQL, so I use VPC access connector.

```
 $ gcloud functions deploy my-function --project=MY-PROJECT --region=asia-northeast1 --runtime=go113 --trigger-event=google.storage.object.finalize --trigger-resource=MY-GCS-BUCKET --source=/path/to/source --entry-point=MyFunction --vpc-connector=projects/MY-PROJECT/locations/asia-northeast1/connectors/MY-VPC-ACCESS-CONNECTOR --egress-settings=all --ingress-settings=internal-only
```

[doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#other-runtimes) says as below, which looks correctly set on my deploy command.

- All functions must use a Serverless VPC Access connector. See Connecting to a VPC network for more information.
- All functions must allow only traffic from internal sources. See Ingress settings for more information.
- All functions must route all outgoing traffic through the VPC network. See Egress settings for more information.

## What happens

After executing gcloud command, I got this error.

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                                     
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Unable to build your function due to VPC Service Controls. The Cloud Build service account associated with this function needs an appropriate access level on the service perimeter. Please grant access to the Cloud Build service account: my-project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com’ by following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#grant-build-access.
```

But on Procedure 1. I added `my-project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` in Access Level Policy [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#grant-build-access)

Once, I tried to modify Access Level Policy; currently it's "AND" condition of IP and IAM, so changed condition as below; I thought cloud build runs not on my IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32).
But it didn't change anything.

※Updated: change 0.0.0.0/32 to 0.0.0.0/0

```
$ gcloud access-context-manager levels describe MY-ACCESS-LEVEL-POLICY

     basic:
      conditions:
      - ipSubnetworks:
        - 0.0.0.0/0 (allow any IP address)
        - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 ( my local machine IP)
        members:
        - serviceAccount:my-project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
        - serviceAccount:service-my-project-number@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

### 2021 Sep.21st updated ===

I got CloudStorage.object.get error before cloudfunctions deploy. Same situation was written in [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting)

Also, I figured out that my access manager policy's condition, which is IPs *AND* members, is the reason. If I remove IP condition, or set condition operator *OR*, then Cloud functions deploy run as I expected.
Which means, serviceaccount called GCP method from unknown IP address, not my local machine's IP.

### ==== 2021 Sep.21st updated

## Question

### 2021 Sep.21st updated

<strike>What configuration was missing to deploy?</strike>

What IP address must be added to `ipSubnetworks`  for cloudbuild-serviceaccount to call method in VPC SC?

Comment: Try with 0.0.0.0/0, not /32 at the end.

Comment: Did you have follow these instructions and the limitations? https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#table_functions

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Sorry, it's mistake just on this post. Actually 0.0.0.0/0 was set  on GCP env

Comment: I didn't set ingress rule, which is written in the limitation. I'll try it  ; Cloud Functions uses Cloud Build to build your source code into a runnable container. In order to use Cloud Functions inside a service perimeter, you must configure an ingress rule for the Cloud Build Service Account in your service perimeter.

Comment: I cannot find what to set ingress rule for Cloud Build `you must configure an ingress rule for the Cloud Build Service Account in your service perimeter.`

Comment: I found that, ingress rule for the Cloud Build Service Account is no need; problem is ipSubnetworks. current condition use AND condition, ipSubnetworks & members. cloud build service account may called from somewhere not from my local machine IP. But no info which IP it is

Comment: The message error says that the Cloud Build service account needs the correct service level.
Did you [grant access](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#grant-build-access) to the Cloud Build service account to the VPC SC?

Comment: @drauedo Yes, I already add that service account  in VPC SC's Access Level. 
 members:
        - serviceAccount:my-project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com 

I figured out problem is IP. currently, my setting VPC access level condition is IP AND members. even if I added my local machine's IP in that condition, I got same error. If I remove IP conditions, build worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#:%7E:text=vpc%20service%20controls%20protection%20is%20available%20only%20for%20builds%20run%20in%20private%20pools.):

> VPC Service Controls protection is available only for builds run in private pools.

So in order to make the cloud build service account able to access the VPC SC you need to set up a [private pool](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/using-vpc-service-controls).

If this does not work, you could also, as suggested in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/using-vpc-service-controls#grant-build-access), use a [user-specified](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts) service accounts instead as it is inside the VPC Service Controls perimeter as long as your project is also inside the perimeter.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.  
I already tried deploy with private worker-pool, but not worked; error didn't change.  About service account, cloudbuild can use custom service-account, but cloudfunction looks not; `gcloud functions deploy` has option to set service-account, which is not for deploy but for executing function itself

Comment: Could you specify which error are you getting now? Is it the same as before?

Comment: yes, same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since there is no helpful log that will guide us to understand what is causing the issue, I suggest you to open a case in Google Cloud Platform support. I work with the Support team and we can help you further by investigating the VPC logs.

Alternatively, maybe you could continue the troubleshooting if you run Cloud Function without fully hardened configuration, and trying to find the callerIp checking the logs.